# Passing arguments through multiple functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I'm currently writing a tic tac toe game in javascript, and I've written the following class to represents the "Computer".

I've included the entire class below, but the method I'm struggling with is `atRiskSquare()`. Here's how it's supposed to work: the method `move()` should get called with a `board` object, and then it should pass that `board` object into `atRiskSquare()` which checks whether any of the squares are at risk (in which case the computer would play a defensive move).

When I console.log the "board" inside of the `move()` method I get an array that represents the board. however, when I console.log the board inside of the `atRiskSquare()` method I get undefined. I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
class Computer extends Player {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static COMPUTER_MOVE = 'O';

  move(board) {
    console.log(board); // **Logs the board**
    if (this.atRiskSquare(board)) {
      this.defensiveMove(this.atRiskSquare(board));
    } else {
      this.randomMove(board, this.atRiskSquare());
    }
  }

  atRiskSquare(board) {
    console.log(board); // **logs undefined**
    let humanMoves = board.findSpaces('X'); // Throws an error. Can't iterate over undefined

    for (let winningCombo of Game.WINNING_COMBOS) {
      let atRiskSquare;
      let count;

      for (let square of winningCombo) {
        if (humanMoves.includes(square)) {
          count += 1;
        } else {
          atRiskSquare = square;
        }
      }

      if (count === 2) {
        return atRiskSquare;
      }

    }
    return null;
  }

  defensiveMove(board, square) {
    board.addMove(square, Computer.COMPUTER_MOVE);
    this.moves.push(square);
  }

  randomMove(board) {
    let openSpaces = board.findSpaces(' ');
    let randomSpace = Math.floor(Math.random() * openSpaces.length);
    let move = openSpaces[randomSpace].toString();

    board.addMove(move, Computer.COMPUTER_MOVE);
    this.moves.push(move);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the snippet of code that is calling these methods, I think you just aren't creating the board early enough.

Comment: What's going on with this line?

`this.randomMove(board, this.atRiskSquare());`

both randomMove and atRiskSquare take one argument, but you have passed 2 to the first, and 0 to the second.

Comment: Ah you're right @N.Kern that was the issue. The random move shouldn't be using atRiskSquare().  I was looking at the wrong method, and completely missed that. It works now. Thanks!